# Ошибка отладчика Visual Studio. В настоящий момент попадание в точку останова не произойдет. Не удалось найти соответствующее расположение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я начинающий кодер... Потребность заключается в том, что бы получить время с сервера (дабы его не мог изменить игрок путем изменения времени на устройстве) Все делал по уроку с YouTube. У автора все работает, у меня ничего не происходит. Вызываю отладчик, он выдает ошибку, вернее отказывается что либо делать в принципе.

"В настоящий момент попадание в точку останова не произойдет. Не удалось найти соответствующее расположение"

Если кто знает, подскажите, может в самом Юнити...в настройках что то не разрешил... под Андроид делаю приложение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас включена отладка в самой юнити?

Comment: зачем вам эти `[Obsolete]`? этот атрибут означает что данный метод устарел и его нельзя использовать.

Comment: Да, отладка включена, все везде рабоатет, кроме этого участка кода.

Относительно метода - Юнити предлагал решить проблему, добавив его ну и от безысходности, я решил записать так, как он просит, но все равно ничего не изменилось, что в таком формате, что без него